# POST and GET without cURL PHP

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I tried some times release POST and GET in this site http://www.sefaz.pe.gov.br/sintegra, but it doesn´t work

```
// POST
$data = array('CNPJ' => '02340534000192', 'consulta' => 'OK', 'vazio' => '');
$html = $this->HTTP_Post('http://www.sefaz.pe.gov.br/sintegra/consulta/consulta.asp',    $data, $cookie);
$arr = split("Set-Cookie:", $html); 
$cookie="";
$count=1; 
while ($count < count($arr)) 
{ 
 $cookie.=substr($arr[$count].";", 0, strpos($arr[$count].";",";")+1); 
 $count++;
} 

// GET after POST
echo $this->get_url('http://www.sefaz.pe.gov.br/sintegra/consulta/exibirResultado.asp', $cookie);
```

I tried file_get_contents and curl too... both without success

```
function get_url($url,$cookie=false)
{
  $url = parse_url($url);
  $query = $url[path]."?".$url[query];
  echo "Query:".$query;
  $fp = fsockopen( $url[host], $url[port]?$url[port]:80 , $errno, $errstr, 30);
  if (!$fp) 
  {
    return false;
  }
  else 
  {
    $request = "GET $query HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $request .= "Host: $url[host]\r\n";
    $request .= "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n";
    if($cookie) $request.="Cookie:   $cookie\n";
    $request.="\r\n";
    fwrite($fp,$request);

    while (!feof($fp)) 
    {
      $result .= fgets($fp, 128);
   }

   fclose($fp);
   return $result;
  }
}

function HTTP_Post($URL,$data,$cookie, $referrer="")
{
  $URL_Info=parse_url($URL);
  if($referrer=="") $referrer="111";
  foreach($data as $key=>$value)
  $values[]="$key=".urlencode($value);
  $data_string=implode("&",$values);
  if(!isset($URL_Info["port"]))
    $URL_Info["port"]=80;
  $request.="POST ".$URL_Info["path"]." HTTP/1.1\n";
  $request.="Host: ".$URL_Info["host"]."\n";
  $request.="Referer: $referer\n";
  $request.="Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n";
  $request.="Content-length: ".strlen($data_string)."\n";
  $request.="Connection: Keep-Alive\n";
  $request.="Cookie:   $cookie\n";
  $request.="\n";
  $request.=$data_string."\n";
  $fp = fsockopen($URL_Info["host"],$URL_Info["port"]);
  fputs($fp, $request);
  while(!feof($fp)) 
  {
    $result .= fgets($fp, 1024);
  }
  fclose($fp);
  return $result;
}
```

functions GET and POST with fsocket.
any ideas are welcome

Thanks

**EDIT 1:**

Thank you, but it doesn´t work. I tried 20 times, but this website doesn´t work...

The browser message appears: **Atenção: Acesso negado! Favor selecionar algum parâmetro de consulta.**

**Caution: Access Denied! Please select a query parameter.**

my code with your code

```
function POST()
{
  $postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
          'CNPJ' => '02340534000192',
          'consulta' => 'OK',
          'vazio' => '',
          'CPF' => '',
          'IE' => '',
          'razaosocial' => ''
         ));

   $headers = array(
                         'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                         'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                        );

  $opts = array('http' =>
    array(
          'method'  => 'POST',
          'header'  => implode("\r\n", $headers),
          'content' => $postdata,
         ));

  $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
  $result = file_get_contents('http://www.sefaz.pe.gov.br/sintegra/consulta/consulta.asp', false, $context);
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: You say "it don't work", how don't it work?

Comment: I don´t know, only this website

Comment: that's a website specific call that you complain about, not the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IP is probably blocked by the website.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do `file_get_contents` for GET
or http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php for `POST`

Example from php.net website

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);
```